# Automatically select option from an array as default based on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm allowing my users to pick an hour, minute and am/pm option. Later, I want them to be able to edit this option. I'm going to focus on hour for the sake of this question, since the same logic will apply to the others as well.

When I user initially chooses their hour, they select a value from a  option. The code looks like this:

```
 <select>
               <?

        foreach($timehours as $key => $value){
        echo "<option name=\"hour1\" value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
        }
            ?>

 </select>
```

And the $timehours list looks like this:

```
    $timehours = array(
'01:'          => "1",
'02:'          => "2",
'03:'          => "3",
'04:'          => "4",
'05:'          => "5",
'06:'          => "6",
'07:'          => "7",
'08:'          => "8",
'09:'          => "9",
'10:'          => "10",
'11:'          => "11",
'12:'          => "12",
);
```

(I'm converting the time, which is why it's like this and I have a substr that cuts off the " : " from the time before putting it into the  dropdown. So never mind that part of it)

Let's say the user selected 08:30pm and the 08 part is called from the db using $hour.

I tried the following code

```
     <select>
               <?

        foreach($timehours as $key => $value){
        echo "<option name=\"hour1\" value=\"$key\">$hour</option>";
        }
            ?>

 </select>
```

and the result was that every option was "08" (listed 12 times). I tried changing $key to $hour and all I got was the one option of "08".

What I'm trying to do is have all 12 hour options display in the drop down () but I guess add on selected="selected" to that particular option? I'm a newbie and am not sure where to begin - this is my first real PHP project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all you should use single quote inside double-quote and vice verse.
2nd, you should put name for select, and not for option.

so your code should look like that:

```
 <select name = 'hour1'>
           <?

    foreach($timehours as $key => $value){
    echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";
    }
        ?>

 </select>
```

P.S. Mix quotes just to make it easier to read

Comment: Thanks! I ended up killing the value part of the array and going with:
 <select>
                    <?

   foreach ($timehours as $key) {
       echo "<option value='$key'";
       if ($key == $hour1) {
           echo " selected";
       }
       echo ">$key</option>\n";
   }
             
             ?>

</select>

Answer (score 0):

Correct one:

```
<select name='hour1'>
foreach($timehours as $key => $text){
    if($key==$hour){
        echo "<option selected value=\"$key\">$text</option>";
    }else{
        echo "<option value=\"$key\">$text</option>";
    }
 }
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, Dracony. I tried it but it didn't work. The result was that the entire array was displayed from $timehours, just like is was when I used $value and not $hour

Comment: Sorry, was a bit sleepy. Try this one =) What you were looking for is the 'selected' sttribute that has to be set for the option the user selected ($hour). Also you set the name for the 'select' element, not for options